# jquery-popup-overlay popup content visible at page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use this plugin [jquery-popup-overlay](https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay) ( has any one used it? ) and I am following this example [demo](http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/). According to this demo the html markup of the popup ( `<div id=popup> <!--content--> </div>` ) resides in the main page. It is hidden on page load and becomes visible only when clicked on the button "my_popup_open". But I cannot see what makes this html markup ( `div< id="my_popup"> ...</div>`) to be hidden at page load. Is there a specific class ( e.g ".hidden{ display:none}" ) used somewhere that tells the browser to hide this markup? the documentation says nothing. In my case when I copy paste this code from the demo site and I include all the .js file required, the content of my popup markup is visible in the main page at page load.

```
<!-- header stuff -->

<body >

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <div id="my_popup_window" class="well ">
        <h4>Some title...</h4>

        <!-- content stuff-->  

        <button class="fade_close btn btn-default">Close</button>
    </div>

    <!-- footer stuff -->

</body>
```

Comment: where is the element with id #my_popup in the DOM???..instead of #my_popup id use only #popup

Comment: sorry I was too quick to post my question...I am updating...

Comment: Are you Include jQuery library ?

Comment: yes <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: The display is controlled by `visibility: visible;` or `visibility: hidden;` style attribute of `well` class.